# WPF: C# code throws XAMLParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm making a WPF application which needs to find a drives name based on the volume label (plus other stuff).

The issue is that when it runs the following code to get the drives it throws a XAMLParseException (Note that this code is part of a static class):

```
public static string driveAdministracion = "";
    public static string driveProyectos = "";
    public static void checkDrives()
    {
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        for (int i=0; i<drives.Count();i++)
        {
            if (drives[i].VolumeLabel == "administracion") { driveAdministracion = drives[i].Name; }
            if (drives[i].VolumeLabel == "proyectos") { driveProyectos = drives[i].Name; }
        }

    }
```

The exception message is in spanish but translated it would be:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The invocation of the constructor on type 'MyNamespace.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '9'.

The weird thing is that if I dont run the code for the drives the program runs normallly

Heres the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ARAINCO_2._0.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ARAINCO_2._0"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an exception generated from checkDrives method. Wrap it in a try catch block to see what is going wrong or check the inner exception of the XamlParseException.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**Ctrl + Alt + E** to open Exception Window, and check all checkboxes. So that the debugger can stop exactly at the error code and you can find what is the actual reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check (or uncheck) "Just my code" option in Settings -> Debug and you will see more error data in output window.